# IP Address Shows instead of Domain Name

Tags: wordpress, azure, dns

I bought a domain name from GoDaddy.com. I configured it to forward to a wordpress website I am hosting on Azure. I used Wordpress VM (preconfigured) to build the web host.

Now, when I go to the domain name, it correctly forward me to the website. But, instead of showing the domain name in the browser, it shows the ip address of the machine.

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

I changed the wp-config.php file (WP_HOME, WP_SITEURL), I added code to funtions.php (theme), I updated the database with the new domain name with no luck. I suspect it is something with Azure.

Comment: _"I configured it to forward to a wordpress website I am hosting on Azure."_ -- what does this mean? CNAME record? A record? Some other way? Can you post your domain name here?

Comment: @evilSnobu I am not sure how godaddy configure forwarding. https://www.godaddy.com/help/manually-forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name-422 sorry.

Comment: Don't forward. Properly set a CNAME instead. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-godaddy-custom-domain-name/

Answer (score 1):

in my case add www. between https:// and domainname.com Example https://domainname.com  To ==> https://www.domainname.com

at WordPress Login to the manage and go to "Settings" > General Settings.
Change "WordPress Address" and "Site Address" to match your domain.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy fix!

1. Login to the manage and go to "Settings".
2. Change "WordPress Address" and "Site Address" to match your domain.

Look at the image in this article

https://serverpilot.io/docs/solution-to-wordpress-showing-ip-address-instead-of-domain/